# SSMS Expand to Multiple Rows based off of Evaluation

Tags: sql, sql-server

First time posting. I attempted to search for a similar scenario but I don't even know the proper terms for what I'm attempting.

Onto the question. I have a CTE dataset with a quantity column. Using this column I need to evaluate against a price layer table which holds quantities at a certain cost. I need to generate an output that sells the units in the price layer table and to determine the correct cost using FIFO methods. This might be better illustrated below.

CTE (simplified):

```
ITEMNMBR    QTY
00378       1000
```

Price Layer Table (Oldest received at top, newest at bottom):

```
ITEMNMBR    QTYREC    QTYSOLD    UNITCOST
00378       500       125        0.45
00378       250       0          0.55
00378       1000      0          0.75
```

Intended Result:
Depending on the QTY of the CTE, I want to progressively sell out the oldest price layers first, continuing until the QTY has been fulfilled.

```
ITEMNMBR    QTY    UNITCOST    TOTALCOST
00378       375    0.45        168.75
00378       250    0.55        137.50
00378       375    0.75        281.25          //This leaves the last price layer with 625 units remaining.
```

More simple example:

CTE (simplified):

```
ITEMNMBR    QTY
05583       250
```

Price Layer Table (Oldest received at top, newest at bottom):

```
ITEMNMBR    QTYREC    QTYSOLD    UNITCOST
05583       500       125        0.2
05583       250       0          0.3
05583       1000      0          0.4
```

Intended Result:

```
ITEMNMBR    QTY    UNITCOST    TOTALCOST
05583       250    0.2         50     //Leaves 125 units in the first price layer
```

I'm not even looking for a solution necessarily, just a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with some hard effort. Using nested cursors and a temp table I was able to get the behavior I needed.

Pseudo-Code:

```
;declare sales_cursor cursor for WITH CTEDateset as (/*CTE Code here*/)

Iterate through every record in sales_cursor

For each record, declare an inner cursor
declare price_cursor cursor for select * from price_layer_table
    For each price layer record, perform math 
        Check if the total quantity fits in a single layer 
              If so add a new record to the temp table and exit out of the inner cursor. 
              If not, subtract the available amount and add a record to the temp table, continue to next price layer with the remaining amount

select * from tempSales
```